# Java `KeyListener` not working

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a game (the repo is [here](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/super-roflcopter)), and I run in an issue: when the game switch to `GamePanel` the keyboard stop working.

`GamePanel.java` correctly call `GUI#registerSpriteManager`, but keyboard actions aren't recorded by the `SpriteManager`.

In `GamePanel.java`

```
public GamePanel(GUI gui) {
    this.gui = gui;
    this.back = new Background(this);

    this.manager = new SpriteManager();
    this.manager.add(new Roflcopter(
        GUI.WIDTH/2,
        GUI.HEIGHT/2
    ));
    gui.regiterSpriteManager(this.manager);

    this.level = new Level1(this.manager);
}
```

In `GUI.java`

```
public void regiterSpriteManager(SpriteManager manager) {
    this.manager = manager;
    this.addKeyListener(manager);
}
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: Please include the relevant portions of your code here in this question instead of linking to it in a repository.

Comment: Please post relevant source code, please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @thst They posted a link to the github repo. All the source code you could ever dream of is there.

Comment: This is not the way to ask. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson You should also read the "how to ask" help page.

Comment: @Tom I don't post links to repos.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson No, but you said that they are enough (well, your comment sounds that way). They aren't and that help page explains why.

Comment: @Tom I'm just pointing out that the code's there. And yes, I've read the page. There's no use in starting arguments with people on SO.

Comment: @TùxCräftîñg The listener seems to be wired up correctly, the problem should be inside the key handler. Did you check in a debugger if your key-listener is actually called?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem by adding `this.setFocusable(true);` in `GUI.java`